# Agrupar los valores de una columna sumando los valores de otra columna

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Tengo una duda que no logro resolver y estoy trabado, no es difícil pero no logro encontrar cómo hacerlo. Mi dataset es el siguiente :

| Nombre | Número |
| --- | --- |
| Juan Pérez | 1 |
| Juan Pérez | 3 |
| Juan Pérez | 2 |
| Alberto Gómez | 4 |
| Alberto Gómez | 1 |
| Pedro Álvarez | 2 |
| Pedro Álvarez | 5 |

Lo que necesito es que me agrupe todas las personas con un mismo nombre y me sume los números que corresponden a cada persona. De esta manera, me debería dar como resultado el siguiente dataset:

| Nombre | Número |
| --- | --- |
| Juan Pérez | 6 |
| Alberto Gómez | 5 |
| Pedro Álvarez | 7 |

Sé que tengo que usar un groupby, pero no se cuál ni cómo. Ya intenté con `df.groupby("Nombre")["Número"].count()` y probé también con sum y con size, pero no resulta. ¿Alguien podría darme una mano?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código que tengas.

Comment: probá con : df.groupby('Nombre')['Número'].sum()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece raro que no te funcione con sum, así que pongo un ejemplo:

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-
import pandas as pd

nombres=['Juan Pérez',
'Juan Pérez',
'Juan Pérez',
'Alberto Gómez',
'Alberto Gómez',
'Pedro Álvarez',
'Pedro Álvarez',]

numeros=[1,3,2,4,1,2,5]
data=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(nombres,numeros)),columns = ['Nombre','Número'])
```

Esto es irrelevante, es la forma que usaré para crear el df

si hago:

```
print(data)
```

Da como resultado:

```
Nombre  Número
0     Juan Pérez       1
1     Juan Pérez       3
2     Juan Pérez       2
3  Alberto Gómez       4
4  Alberto Gómez       1
5  Pedro Álvarez       2
6  Pedro Álvarez       5
```

y ahora usaré:

```
agrupados= data.groupby('Nombre')['Número'].sum()
print(agrupados)
```

Resultado:

```
Nombre
Alberto Gómez    5
Juan Pérez       6
Pedro Álvarez    7
```

Si no entendí el planteo, perdón.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Evidentemente es esa la función que tengo que usar, pero no está funcionando bien porque en el dataset que tengo deja por separado algunos nombres que están escrito exactamente igual. Al menos ahora tengo la certeza de que el problema es otro y no la función que estoy usando, voy a ver cómo lo puedo resolver. Repito el agradecimiento ya que puedo avanzar nuevamente con lo que estaba trabajando.